# C++ Find last char in char array

Tags: c++, string, char, find

Basically I'm trying to find last char in a char* array.
e.g; I have this string:

```
"This is a long string with many other \"characters\". Hehehe"
```

I tried to use this:

```
int findLast (const char* buffer, int pos, char character, int size)
{
    int last = 0;

    for (int i = pos; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == character)
            last = i;
        if (buffer[i] == '\n')
            return last;
    }

    return last;
}
```

Like this:

```
int lastCharPos = findLast ( charArray, ftell(file), '"', charSize );
```

In the charArray we have:

```
"This is a long string with many other \"characters\". Hehehe"
```

findLastChar returns the pos of " that comes after "characters", but the last one should be after Hehehe.

The idea is to return the position of the last "char" specified by user request, however it doesn't work.

I'm trying to use it with this string:

```
"Welcome to Stackoverflow!\nWe seriously hope you have a \"great\" time."
```

It returns (the code says the " after great is the last one, but as you can see in the given string, it's not):

```
"Welcome to Stackoverflow!\nWe seriously hope you have a \"great\"
```

Trying to use it to search for "

Comment: What do you mean, it returns `"Welcome to Stackoverflow!\nWe seriously hope you have a \"great\"`? You are returning an `int`, not a `char *` or a `std::string`.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: Perhaps you are not calling your function correctly?

Comment: Last char in string is `\0`, not `\n` in `if (buffer[i] == '\n')`, or you want to stop processing after `Stackoverflow!`?

Comment: I think output it returns is fine because you are searching for `"` , and after **great\"** is the last occurrence of `"`.

Comment: basically I read the string in the loop, after I found the first " I proceed to findLast (charArray, ftell(file), '"', charSize); it should return the last pos of the given char, but it doesn't work, it returns the pos of the last " before the real last " is found.

Comment: Can you please explain which is the real last position.

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro You do know that the `"`s you put in the code to signify strings don't become part of the strings, right?

Comment: "Hello my name is \"Raul\" and I'm 20 years old" in that given string the last " should be after old, however the code returns the " after Raul and skips the rest, which doesn't make sense since the last " in the strnig comes after "old"

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro The closing `"` is not part of the string, it's just part of how you specify a literal string in C/C++. The actual value of the string is `Hello my name is "Raul" and I'm 20 years old` -- so the `"` character after `Raul` is indeed the last `"` character in the string.

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro Could you update the question to include *exactly* how you specify your strings?

Comment: Because `"` after **old** not the part of the string. if you want to make the part of the string use like this `"Hello my name is \"Raul\" and I'm 20 years old\" "`

Comment: Also one more suggestion if you want to find last occurrence traverse your array in reverse direction and return when you find first instance from the last. This will improve your time complexity.

Comment: @Biffen I'm reading every char from a FILE using fgetc, so " chars are there.

Comment: @Learner chars are there I'm reading within a FILE with fgetc not from std::string.

Comment: Are those quotes actually part of the string? Or just delimiters from a string literal? A _testcase_ written in _code_ would make this question much clearer.

Comment: Are you sure you get the size correctly? Maybe its one off, and you are missing last char. You could print in for loop what chars are investigated

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro OK, that changes things. But you could still easily convert the `char*` to an `std::string` and use one of its many `find...()` functions.

Comment: @Learner: It doesn't affect the time complexity whatsoever. O(n) either way. It will usually result in increased speed, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Imagine theres a text file and the contents are as follows **"Welcome to Stackoverflow!\nWe seriously hope you have a \"great\" time."** every " is in the text, don't get confused.

Comment: @RafalMielniczuk Yes, size is correct.

Comment: Then your size is _not_ correct. It is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this is tagged c++, so dont use `char*`

```
#include <string>

int findLastPos( std::string s, char c )
{
     return s.rfind( string(1,c) );
}
```

Comment: The thing is that function won't work if my "string/char*" is composed as follows: **"usernamename"\n\n"other user\"no other\", return user"** that's why my function includes a current position in array, so that it doesn't complicate the main procedure process I want (get the last " from the given buffer based in position).

Comment: yes it will. you seem to be confused regarding how strings are handled. put that text in a .txt file, read it into a std::string, and try it. it will work

Comment: the problem you are having is not in the character searching, it happens elsewhere

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro Your example in your comment is not a valid string literal. It is escaped improperly.  Also, look at the description of rfind() here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind  Now tell me, what magical string do you have that can defeat what `rfind` does?

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro - Works correctly -- returns 49 as the position of the last double quote:  http://ideone.com/c04cN3